# How can I keep multiple ActiveRecord instances of the same database row in sync?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my Rails application I have these models

```
Order has_many OrderItem
OrderItem belongs_to Order
```

My controller has this (pseudo) code:

```
#before_filter
@cart = Order.find(session[:cart_id])

#Action: update_item
item = OrderItem.find(params[:item_id] 
#The order, item belongs to, is in fact @cart, i.e. @cart.id == item.order.id
item.price = 999.99
item.order.total += item.price
```

After the last line the `@cart` object still has the old `total` value.

What's the best way to solve such situations in Rails? I guess the simplest way would be to just reload `@cart` but perhaps there's a more Rails-like way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you save the item before getting the total from @cart

```
item = OrderItem.find(params[:item_id])
item.price = 999.99
item.save!
```

And to get the total from item's order can be:

```
total_price = item.order.order_items.sum(&:price)
```

I am assuming the relationship between Order and OrderItem is

```
class Order
has_many :order_items
...
end

class OrderItem
belongs_to :order
...
end
```

The @cart can be reloaded as follow

```
@cart.reload
```

OR to get the updated total

```
@cart.reload.order_items.sum(&:price)
```

Hopefuly it helps